# how to make servlets send applets to the same html page that has the form

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I am very very new to this. and yeah it's a homework.
I am trying to make an HTML page with a form to send some variables to a servlet and the servlet sends an applete to the same form page. so far i succeeded in sending the applet alone. I tried using jQuery, but i couldn't send the HTML tags. I can only send text.

My code so far:

index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> title </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action = "Servlet">
  <input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="5" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form> 
</body>
```

Servlet.java

```
    package ServletPackage;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Servlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String nm;


    nm = request.getParameter ("Name");



    PrintWriter mess = response.getWriter();

    mess.println("<html>");
    mess.println("<head>");
    mess.println("</head>");
    mess.println("<body>");
    mess.println("<b> You've entered Name: </b>" + nm);


    mess.println("<p align=center>");
    mess.println("<applet code='NameInShape.class' width=200 height=200>");
    mess.println("<param name='NAME'      value='" + nm + "'>");
    mess.println(" </applet>");
    mess.println("</p>");
    mess.println("</html>");
    mess.println("</body>");
    mess.close();
}


public static void main( String[] args )

{   }


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) to call a .jsp (JavaServer Pages) clone of your index.html with the parameters posted by your form. And don't worry, it's pretty simple to implement. The result will look like the initial page the form still available, but the applet will be called using the specified parameters.

You need to import RequestDispatcher  (`import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;`) and then you can do something like this in your doPost method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("clone.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

The method `rd.forward(request, response);` makes the parameters posted to your servlet available on the `clone.jsp` page, and you can insert them using `<%=request.getParameter("ParameterName")%>` inside the .jsp page.

For example, after adding the above code in your servlet, you could insert something like this in the `clone.jsp` page to embed the applet with a parameter received from the `index.html` form submission:

```
<applet code=Applet.class width=300 height=300>
    <param name=NAME value="<%=request.getParameter("NAME")%>">
</applet>
```